# How to I reset wireless card without rebooting?

Tags: restart, wifi-hardware-switch

I have Qualcomm Atheros that I pulled from my old laptop and inserted it into my current computer ever now and then it doesn't mount and I have to restart my computer just to get it to work. This doesn't seem to hardware specific. I can't just pull it out and put it back in like I did with my other ones and it's inconvenient to shutdown turn back on every time. Is there command I can use to reset and get to show up or am I restarting my system every time I need it to show?

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart`.